# Any advice for starting with Heidegger's What is Called Thinking

Tags: heidegger

I thought I might pick up a copy, see what he's saying there.

Any advice, things to look out for, half baked rebuttals of the project?

Answer (score 1):

The title is a slightly misleading translation.  Most emphasis is on "What calls for thinking" or "What calls thinking", with overlays on calling thinks thanks, so giving thanks.  Nice essay though.